# Why did the Votans come to Earth in particular?

Tags: defiance

After watching the pilot episode, I took a look at Wikipedia for more information on the [different Votan species](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defiance_(TV_series)#Votans), and this caught my eye:

> The Votanis star system was destroyed in a stellar collision 5,000 years ago, but the millions of Votans who fled in ark-ships made the long interstellar journey in hypersleep
>   ...
>   The Votanis star system was located in the Perseus Arm of the Milky Way galaxy.

(The Defiance Wiki confirms, [the Perseus arm with a reference](http://en.defiance-wiki.com/wiki/Votanis_System), and also mentions the 5000 years [on another page](http://en.defiance-wiki.com/wiki/Vysu))

So wait a minute...

[image: Our section of the galaxy]

To get *here* from almost anywhere in the Perseus arm, they would've been passing through relatively empty space, where it was less likely they'd find a new planet to settle on.

Why did they send their ships in this direction?  Did they go through the Perseus Transit and it was just a coincidence?  Or was there another reason they went in the direction of Earth, going through the empty space between galactic arms, and reducing their chances of finding a planet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, my suspicions were confirmed in episode 1x12, the Season 1 finale, [Everything is Broken](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_Broken_%28Defiance%29):

> An ancient ship, the Kaziri, crashed on Earth and is hidden at the bottom of the town mines.  To quote Nolan and Doctor Yewll, it has a weapon that can "kill every human being on the planet - or every Votan, depending on how you use it".
>
>  According to the Earth Republic representative, the Indogene have been searching for it for almost 3000 years.  Given that they were not active while in the 5000 year hypersleep journey to Earth, this would seem to indicate the ship was discovered by Indogene around 8000 years ago.  The stellar collision in the Votanis system 5000 years ago would simply have been an excuse to make the journey.
>  
>  *Aside, I do not call it an Indogene ship as the technology behind it that we've seen so far doesn't look Votan in origin.  And the search would seem to indicate that the weapon aboard is stronger than the Indogene (the most technologically advanced of the Votan) are capable of.*

Answer (score 4):

After watching the pilot episode, I took a look around on wiki and other sites to learn more information on the Votan races and their home star system. Their system was destroyed in a stellar collision, but the Votans already knew this was going to happen, so they built the arks and made the 5000 year journey in hypersleep. As I was researching for more information, I found the quote, "the Votans did not think Earth was inhabited". So that would reference that the Votan already knew about Earth and plotted their course towards Earth for a new home.

Answer (score 1):

So why did they come to the one planet where they suspected the long-lost Kaziri ship would be?  Is the Ark fleet actually to save themselves from stellar catastrophe, or is it a cleverly-disguised expedition to retrieve that ship- and possibly get rid of certain elements of Votan society in the process?

The series lore says that the Liberata are purposefully meek and subservient in order to make up for horrible transgressions in the past.  Might the transgressions of the Irathient be even greater- leading them to abandon technology and civilization altogether?  It's clear that the ancient Kaziri was of their design- the "snake cult" was right- it was an Irathient who must possess the keys and reactivate the ship.   The Irathient were likely the "top" most advanced race at one point in time, to be able to make such a thing, and that was long ago.

The Indogenes definitely knew these things- with a special task force to find that ship.
The E-Rep knows about it too.